# "Escalpelo" vs. "bisturí"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones, vocabulario-médico

Mientras visionaba un vídeo en inglés sobre restauración de cuadros, noté que el narrador utilizaba la palabra *scalpel* para referirse a lo que yo normalmente llamo "**bisturí**". Esto me hizo recordar que, en algunas ocasiones, también he oído en español llamar "**escalpelo**" al bisturí.

En el DLE aparecen ambas:

> [**bisturí**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5cB56NY)
>   Del fr. *bistouri*.
>
> 1. m. Instrumento en forma de cuchillo pequeño, de hoja fija en un mango metálico, que sirve para hacer incisiones en tejidos blandos.

> [**escalpelo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=G7dZdo0)
>   Del lat. *scalpellum*.
>
> 1. m. Med. Instrumento en forma de cuchillo pequeño, de hoja fina, puntiaguda, de uno o dos cortes, que se usa en las disecciones anatómicas, autopsias y vivisecciones.

Las definiciones son muy parecidas, pero la de "escalpelo" parece más detallada, y ninguna de las dos redirige a la otra.

Mi pregunta es: **¿son realmente sinónimas?** Es decir, ¿es lo mismo un escalpelo que un bisturí?
Y en caso de que lo sean, ¿cuál de las dos es la más usada o establecida?

Comment: Interesante que el DRAE no los enlace, en la página de wikipedia sí aparecen como sinónimos https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalpelo Quizás algún profesional de la Medicina pueda responder mejor a tus cuestiones, a ver si hay suerte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a [mentorlinguistico](https://mentorlinguistico.wordpress.com/2014/01/):

> [L]a diferencia entre ambos radica en que **el BISTURÍ usa cuchillas intercambiables** -contrario a su definición oficial-; en cambio, el ESCALPELO es de hoja fija.
>
> [...] Atendiendo a su definición, concluyo que ambos, sin lugar a dudas, son instrumentos usados en cirugía; sin embargo, técnicamente, las autopsias sólo se hacen con ESCALPELO, y no con BISTURÍ, dejando éste para utilizarlo en operaciones de menor importancia.

Este artículo detalla otras herramientas similares como las **lancetas**. También podemos encontrar una diferencia en el artículo [*El bisturí en Medicina*](http://tomascabacas.com/el-bisturi-en-medicina/), atendiendo al uso, que no al tema de las cuchillas intercambiables.

> [El bisturí] es similar al escalpelo, que viene del latín “scalpellum”, que se define también como instrumento en forma de cuchillo pequeño, de hoja fina, puntiaguda, de uno o dos cortes **que se usa en disecciones anatómicas, autopsias y vivisecciones**.

La propia [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalpelo) añade (para el " **escalpelo** o **bisturí**, también llamado **lanceta** o **cuchillo de cirujano**") que:

> Algunos consideran que el término bisturí se refiere específicamente al instrumento cuya hoja es extraíble e intercambiable o retráctil respecto al mango y que escalpelo es aquel con la hoja fija o con la parte cortante haciendo cuerpo con el mango.

Básicamente, ambos términos parecen referirse al mismo tipo de herramienta, siendo prácticamente intercambiables (en el lenguaje). Considerar a un tipo de instrumento *bisturí* o *escalpelo* puede ser un tecnicismo refiriéndose al tipo de cuchillas del mismo.

Answer (score 7):

El *Diccionario terminológico de ciencias médicas*, 11ª ed. Salvat Editores (1974) define:

> **Escalpelo**
>   Instrumento cortante, puntiagudo, de uno o dos filos y mango, que se emplea en las disecciones y operaciones quirúrgicas.

y

> **Bisturí**
>   Cuchillo quirúrgico, largo y estrecho, recto o curvo. El bisturí propiamente dicho tiene la hoja articulada con el mango, compuesto de dos cachas, entre las cuales se oculta aquella cuando el instrumento está cerrado. El bisturí fijo se denomina también *escalpelo*.